# Remove a bar in my app project

Tags: android

Please i'm working for a pdf viewer, and i want to remove this bar "Myapp"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98YUa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme to something like AppCompat.NoActionBar, and create a TextView with full width and put anything there